# Vector Surface integral of a Cube

Tags: complex-analysis, surface-integrals

Evaluate $${\int \int}_S \underline{F} \cdot d \underline{a}$$

$$\underline{F} = (y+z, x+z, y+x)$$

$S$ is the portion of the surface of the cube bounded by the planes
$x=0, y=0, z=0, x=1,y=1,z=1$ with outward normal.

I have a solution where it seems like they parametrised the 6 squares of the cube. I just don't understand how we would get these parametrisations?

E.g.

$$S_1^{-}: \underline r_1^- = (u,1,v)^{T}$$

$$S_2: \underline r_2 = (u,v,1)^{T}$$

Comment: Hint: [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) plus $\nabla \cdot F = 0$ implies no need to evaluate the integral explicitly.

Comment: I know this but the point of this exercise is to see how to do it explicitly I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of these is the square where $y=1$; it is parametrized by $0\le u, v\le 1$ (where $u$ and $v$ represent the $x$ and $z$ coordinates). The second is the square where $z=1$, parametrized by $0\le u, v \le 1$ (where $u$ and $v$ represent the $x$ and $y$ coordinates). Have you tried drawing a picture and thinking about what a general point on each face looks like?

Comment: Oh wait I see I can visualise it now. So y stays 1 and the other 2 are parametrised and we restrict them accordingly

Comment: but what about the reversed orientation. Where does that come from? How do we even know what the orientation is

Comment: The parametrizations do not determine the orientation. You only get the orientation when choosing a particular normal to each piece of the parametrization. In your case, the outward pointing normal points from the planes lying along $x, y, z=1$ towards higher coordinates, and from those lying along $x, y, z=0$ towards negative coordinates.

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions seem stupid. I just haven't done this stuff before. Am I right that I should get the parametrisation. i.e. $(u,1,v)^T$ for example then get $\frac{d}{du}(u,1,v)^T= (1,0,0)^T $ and $\frac{d}{dv}(u,1,v)^T = (0,0,1)$ then get the cross product $(0,-1,0)^T$ which is below so negative?

Comment: and if we do the same thing, the cross product for the derivatives of $(u,v,1)^T$ gives $(0,0,1)^T$ which is one that is at the edge of the surface so this one has a positive orientation

Comment: The cross product gives you $(0,-1,0)$, as you point out. But you want the *outward*-pointing normal, so instead you should use $(0,1,0)$. Similarly, on the opposite face, you will also get $(0,-1,0)$, which you want to use since it is outward-pointing. Again, the cross product gives you one of the two normals; which one you get depends on the order you took the cross product in, and which one you want depends on your desired orientation (a matter of geometry, not vector calculus).

Comment: I just don't understand the difference between outward and inward normals

Comment: Again, draw a picture. In your case, of a cube, it should be intuitively clear what an "outward" normal means. At the point $(1/2, 1, 1/2)$, the vector $(0,1,0)$ points outward (from the cube), while the vector $(0,-1,0)$ points inward. It's important that you choose a consistent set of normals across the parametrizations of your surface so that you consistently measure the field flow, either inwards or outwards.

Comment: so is it inwards into the middle of the cube or is there a direction outside the cube thats either inward or outward

Comment: Yes, inwards is into the middle of the cube.

Comment: Oh okay I think I'm starting to get it. So we look at the fact that on any point of this square that we parametrized, the vector (0,1,0) will point outwards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27319/discussion-between-rogerl-and-stephancasey).